# Search For The Comma Separated Values In MYSQL Column

Tags: mysql, sql

genreTable:

| id | genre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pop |
| 2 | Rock |
| 3 | Electro |

songTable:

| id | name | genre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Song1 | 1 |
| 2 | Song2 | 1,2 |
| 3 | Song3 | 2,3 |

Problem: Lets say I want to build query like:

```
SELECT * FROM songTable WHERE genre = '1'
```

It'll only return Song1

But how Do I make sure it also returns Song1, Song2

Any other suggestions regarding re-structuring the table is also accepted...

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your data model!  There are many reasons why your data model is broken:

- Columns should only contain one value.
- Numbers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL has pretty bad string processing capabilities.

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad design decisions.  In that case, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
select s.*
from songTable s
where find_in_set('1', genre) > 0
```

Comment: Then how should i save the genres? I mean if one song have more than 1 Genre, what should be the proper way to structuring the database...